# Weird urls after moving site from local env to a server

Tags: wp-admin, url-rewriting, urls, server

I've noticed after moving website to a server post slugs started looking something like `78a6a04c0d498postname78a6a04c0d498`.

Comment: I found this change in the DB table `wp_options` in `permalink_structure` row. It must have something to do with the process of moving the database to a new server.

Comment: How did you migrated the site? Used any plugin or did it manually?

Comment: I did it manually

Comment: It shouldn't if done right. I'd recommend [following this article](https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/) in a clean database.